# Constraint of 77 columns in Artistic Style(Good indentation tool)

Tags: c++

I am using Artistic Style version 1.24(http://astyle.sourceforge.net/) for indenting the C++ program but while indentation,it crosses the column 78.Does it contain any option to prevent this?

Comment: 77 columns is a pretty small limit. Most screens these days can handle wider lines :-).

Comment: @Douglas: although keeping low (lower than ~80) is still great for readability, and should be used whenever possible

Comment: +1 for teaching me about ASTYLE.

@Douglas, most screens can indeed handle wider lines, but for printing you don't want to have lines that are too long (wrapping).  Printing on landscape is not ideal either.  And not everyone has A3 printers.

Answer (score 1):

According to their bug tracker, no it isn't possible. [See this enhancement request](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=986722&group_id=2319&atid=102319).

> It would save us time in the post-conversion cleanup phase if astyle would choose appropriate wrap points to ensure, within reasonable limits, that lines are all within the house coding style maximum line length.

And the maintainer responds with:

> Certainly something I will look into in a future release.

This was quite some time ago, but it appears to still be the case.